# Control Number of Managed Package Custom Object records that can be created using Licensing

Tags: managed-package, lma, fma, packagelicense

I'd like to control the number of `namespace__Team__c` records that can be created using either the `LMA` or `FMA` for our Managed Packaging.

We could write a `Trigger` to control/limit the number of records that can be created.

But I need a way to remotely be able assign more licenses to allow more records to be created.

But I am not clear how to achieve this.

1. Is it possible to have multiple `PackageLicense` assigned to an org for a given Managed Package?
2. Do I add a `FeatureParameterInteger` using the `Feature Management App`, and increment the value to allow more records to be created?
3. What is the correct solution for this challenge?

Comment: You're headed down the right path with #2 in my experience. Your LMO will contain the values for each subscriber's limits for a given feature and then your app's code will check the values at runtime. [ISV Guide: LMO-to-Subscriber Feature Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_lmo_to_subscriber.htm)